# How to prevent this debugger error: to prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function

Tags: c#

I have a small winform tool with several jobs running in the background. They are triggered in a separate thread by calling `StartPgTaskAsync` which was introduced to avoid freezing the UI but it seems to have an adverse effect on the debugger.

I often get this error message:
To prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.ToString' all threads were allowed to run. This may have changed the state of the process and any breakpoints encountered have been skipped.

var PgTask = PgTaskManager.StartPgTaskAsync(taskName);
       await ficTask;

```
  public static Task StartPgTaskAsync(string taskName)
  {
       var task = Task.Run(() => StartPgTask(TaskName));
       return task;
  }
```

Is there something wrong doing the above ?

Comment: I am using Vs2019 and do not wish to use the compatbility mode unless understanding the underlying issue.

Comment: This was resolved by disabling ReSharper